# function Call trace for drupal

Tags: php, debugging, drupal

Drupal is platform developed in PHP , Just like any other sophisticate platform ,
doing ususal things becomes easy and debugging 10 times tough.

I wanted to know , how a page was constructed in drupal.

from the moment i request the server , to final delivery.

List of all function called and in the order they were called.
What tool to use ?

Comment: _What tool to use?_ That would be a "debugger", for example [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 0):

That would be an awful lot of function calls, and I'm not sure that's the best way to start your debugging process. But if you're asking what tools to use, i'd say the Devel module is essential to debugging Drupal, and it will provide you with the function [ddebug_backtrace()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/ddebug_backtrace/7) which will help you navigate the call stack.
I'm not sure how to make it list all calls made during a page request, though, so it's not an answer to that part of your question.